# getHours() is giving a wrong value In React - Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have following Javascript code to get the hour and display if it's morning, night etc. But getHours() is always giving a wrong value to me. If I use in Browser its correct but with react native its always a wrong value. Any bug in this code?

```
    let date = new Date();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = allMonths[date.getMonth()];
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let hour = date.getHours();
    let minute = date.getMinutes();
    let greeting = '';
    if(day < 10){
        day = '0'+day;
    }

    if(hour < 12 ){
        greeting = 'Morning!';
    }else if(hour < 13 && hour >= 12){
        greeting = 'Afternoon!';
    }else if(hour < 18 && hour >= 13){
        greeting = 'Evening!';
    }else {
        greeting = 'Night!';
    }
```

Comment: Your time ranges are odd, but your code does look isomorphic, what exactly is going wrong in react native compared to your browser? Is your phone device time correct? Have you tried it on multiple devices?

Comment: It is possible you're seeing the results of https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12288

Comment: use momentjs instead

Comment: @wizebin I am using Genymotion Emulator right now

Comment: @Jigar I will try Thanks..

Comment: `if(hour < 13 && hour >= 12)` ... so `if(hour == 12)`

Comment: @JaromandaX The issue is not the if condition right now. I am always having a wrong value as the hour.  I also need to improve that If condition . Any suggestions will appreciate,

Comment: you say "it's wrong" ... how so? is it off by, say, your timezone perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX the thing is same code run by browser and giving me correct hour. but in emulator its different

Comment: Different. Yes. In what way. Higher? Lower? Is it a unicorn? A paperclip?

Comment: @JaromandaX its always a lower value

Comment: By how much? He asked, extracting another tooth

Comment: @JaromandaX If i used getUTCHours() then always 5 hours missing. if I use getHours() then its seems random hours missing. Could be it because of the emulator i am using?

Comment: so, you're at UTC+5? random hours? really? like, if you run your code 10 times, what values do you get for hours? This emulator, can you see what timezone it thinks it is in?

Comment: @JaromandaX Well thanks for trying to help but u just only asking question by question I didnt even get a single answer. Anyway thanks for the time. I guess it the emulator.

Comment: Programming is hard. Debugging is harder. Debugging someone else's code is even harder again

Comment: @JaromandaX I hope so. Thanks for the try